# Spring boot with maven for parent project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am having a spring boot maven project, whose name is "CSMaster", it contains the common code which i use in my another projects (AppAdmin).

**CSMaster Project Contains-**
All common code like domains, repository layer, service layer and its pom.xml file.

**AppAdmin Project Contains-**
Controller layer, its helper classes, jsp files and its pom.xml file.
In this controller layer we have autowired the service layer which is present in Master Project.

Now while writing code i am able to access all the methods of Parent Project in AppAdmin Project but while generating war of AppAdmin Project by mvn install then its throwing following error-

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.996 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-26T13:07:25+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/280M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project AppAdmin: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/ttnd/sumit/zzzLearning/repo/boot_appadmin/src/main/java/com/appadmin/helper/PermGroupHelper.java:[10,27] package com.csmaster.domain does not exist
```

It is not picking up master project classes while creating the build.

My Pom files are-

**CSMaster:  pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.csmaster</groupId>
    <artifactId>CSMaster</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CSMaster</name>
    <description>MasterProject</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**AppAdmin: pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.appadmin</groupId>
    <artifactId>AppAdmin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>AppAdmin</name>
    <description>AppAdmin</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Parent Jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csmaster</groupId>
            <artifactId>CSMaster</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How can i fix it..???

Comment: `package com.csmaster.domain does not exist`. Your code doesn't compile...

Comment: package com.csmaster.domain exists in the CSMaster project, and AppAdmin Project is compiling and running perfectly, But when i trying to build war for AppAdmin at that time its not able to locate CSMaster Project classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSMaster dependency is runtime and as per [maven introduction guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope);

**runtime:**

> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for
>   compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test
>   classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

Change your dependency declaration scope from runtime to compile as below;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.csmaster</groupId>
        <artifactId>CSMaster</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It Worked for me.. Thanks